# Способ выделения

Tags: javascript, php

**Имеется:**

[image]

Табличка с координатами из БД, в которой храниться значение X, Y и TYPE. Type несет в себе значение цвета координаты (для восприятия скажу что это карта игры).

**Требуется:** Массово и удобно редактировать цвет координат. К примеру, выделить цвет из палитры, и мышкой рисовать по координатам как карандашом по пикселям в фотошопе. Либо что-то попроще, но удобней чем из выпадающего списка выбирать цвет.

**Вопрос:** Как это лучше реализовать? Хочу заметить, что данную работу я делаю для тренировок в `php`. Так сказать поставил перед собой задачу и выполнил. Теперь хочу просто добавить функциональности и удобства, так как могу сделать и по другому, но способ не дает возможности быстро вносить изменения на большую карту. Но в тоже время, не хочу вникать в подробности `javascript` или еще чего. Знаю, что нужно, но не сейчас.

Теперь без болтовни, может кто видел или знает как реализовать что то подобное? Буду очень благодарен за примеры кода.

Comment: Это как раз будет тренировка по JS, а не по PHP.

Comment: Тогда хоть посоветуйте в каком направлении копать, или напутствие какое, ибо не знаю с чего начать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [Color Picker - jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).

- Почитай про события в `jquery`;
- Напиши функцию, которая считывает выбранный цвет и записывает его в `css` свойство квадрата игрового поля;
- Назначь выше написанную функцию на событие выбора цвета.

P.S.:[jQuery ColorPicker — выбираем цвет](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42996/).